# EditText Control not showing in Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am following along with [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) tutorial and it says

> The default weight for all views is 0, so if you specify any weight
>   value greater than 0 to only one view, then that view fills whatever
>   space remains after all views are given the space they require. So, to
>   fill the remaining space in your layout with the EditText element,
>   give it a weight of 1 and leave the button with no weight.

You achieve this by writing

```
<EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />
```

which I have done. I have also set the `layout_width` to `0dp` as the tutorial says.

Now, in Android Studio, everything appears fine in the Preview pane. But when I debug my app, the `EditText` control does **not** appear. But the Button appears further down the screen and to the very left as if the `EditText` control has actually filled the entire width of the screen and pushed it down (except the `EditText` does not appear so I cannot confirm this).

I have removed the weight property and set a fixed width on it, and *that* gets it to display, but obviously, that is not desirable.

Why won't the `EditText` control appear?

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see below, there is no EditText control.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: Your editText will cover appx. 70% and your button will cover remaining of total width...actually if you use 0dp width approach, you have to set it for all views afaik....

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
              android:layout_weight="3"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Comment: When you say all "views", do you mean all "controls" or all "pages/windows/screens"? Sorry, but this is my first Android app. I come from C++.

Comment: All controls and layouts (Like linearlayout, relative...)

Comment: nope..not all views...just views in you linear layout...in this case it is your edittext and button only...

Comment: @VikramSingh Actually, I just noticed something. (even with your code), when I launch my app, for a split second I can see the EditText appear as it should but it then very, very quickly disappears.

Comment: @VikramSingh I thought I just got it working, but nope. The EditText now appears _but_ it doesn't size correctly the width is very small and I believe the weight is not what I set it to (3).

Comment: you can try to change weight parameter to adjust their width..more the weight,more the space they acquire in their immediate parent layout..

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this in you `editText`:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Replace with this :

```
android:layout_width="107dip"
```

Comment: thank you. I will try this out now. Can you please explain a little more? I'm new to Android dev and some of these things really confuse me.

Comment: Your are assigning width `0dip` to `EditText` due to this it is not visible you should assign greater then 0 or `wrap_content` to make visible

Comment: sorry harish, setting width 107dip is not the solution..he/she is using weight to set the layout width...

Comment: Oh, ok. I get it. The tutorial said it will fill available space with 0dp, so not sure why they said that :-/

Comment: @HarishGodara I just tried your code and it doesn't change anything. The EditText does not appear.

Comment: Then assign some `weight` to button also